# Echo php message if Preg_Match_All doesnt find anything

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Ok if my `preg_match_all` doesn't find anything with my snippet below how can I get it to like echo a message saying None available? I don't have access to the urls in the snippet.

Snippet:

```
<?php
//Urls to scrape from.
$URLs = array();
$URLs[] = 'https://namemc.com/u/Zapdos';
$working = '';

//Curl scraper.
foreach($URLs as $URL){
$ch     = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
$text = strip_tags($page);
$accounts = array();
preg_match_all('/(\w+) \s+ is \s+ available/x',$text,$accounts);
foreach($accounts[0] as $account){
    $working .= ''.$account.''. PHP_EOL . '';
}
}

//Put the scraped proxies into the new .txt file.
file_put_contents('accounts.txt', $working, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check it like this:

```
$result = preg_match_all('/(\w+) \s+ is \s+ available/x',$text,$accounts);
if ($result===false) {
    // preg_match_all didn't find anything
} else {
    // do something with matches...
}
```

You can find more here [preg_match_all](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)